# Django return string from URL dispatcher

Tags: django

Is there any way to return 'hello world' string from bare django project (without creating app and views.py)?

Something like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', plaint_text_module, 'Hello World!'),
)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add inline lambda (or view callable for that matter):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', lambda request: HttpResponse('Hello World!'), name='hello_world'),
)
```

Comment: Be sure to add:

    `from django.http import HttpResponse`

Comment: Newer syntax: `from django.urls import path; path('', lambda request: HttpResponse('Hello World!')),`